# How to add array filter in VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, compare

I want to make code that lookup the values from column AB 
and compares to column F. If column F value matches from column AB, I would like to setup validation code that column S must be xxxx. Otherwise exit out of the code.

```
 With Sheets("testing")
        eFilters = .Range("AB1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp)).Value
```

I got the first part, but can't figure out the comparing part of the coding.

Any suggestion helps!

Comment: Check out `If... Then... End If` syntax for the overall structure.  And the `Exit Sub` statement will "exit out of the code."

Comment: What happens if column AB and column F are both empty? And when you say exit out of the code, is this when xxxx is not found in column S when column F matches AB, or when there is not a match between column F and AB? Do you mean enter xxxx column S when F and AB match? (I had assumed no due to the use of the word validation but am now questioning myself).

Comment: Pretty sure the code you have posted won't compile and where does array come into this? Are you planning on reading the ranges into an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example code will do what you want. You can modify to meet your needs.

```
Sub test()
Dim f As String
Dim ab As String

f = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").Value
ab = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AB1").Value

If f = ab Then
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("S1").Value = "xxxx"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you assume the cell values are strings or is that partly what you meant by modify?